# RCUTILS logging macro vs ROS_INFO

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Community,
I am starting to studying ROS2 in order to start to work with Realtime and Lifecycle nodes. I would like to ask which are the differences between the `rcutils` and the classical debugging/printout methods provided by ROS2 like `ROS_INFO`.
The usage of these tools like `rcutils` have better performances for realtime and are suitable for these applications?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375900/rcutils-logging-macro-vs-ros_info/) by [Kappa95](https://answers.ros.org/users/61250/kappa95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2021-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should not matter too much, because the RCLCPP logging macros (which [replace the `ROS_INFO` calls from ROS 1](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Contributing/Migration-Guide.html#changing-c-library-calls)) are implemented by using `rcutils`. [See for instance `RCLCPP_DEBUG`](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/logging_8hpp.html#a44818c8a1fd292cd0e81759e956765d7):

```
  do { \
    static_assert( \
      ::std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(logger)>::type>::type, \
      typename ::rclcpp::Logger>::value, \
      "First argument to logging macros must be an rclcpp::Logger"); \
 \
    RCUTILS_LOG_DEBUG_NAMED( \
      logger.get_name(), \
      rclcpp::get_c_string(RCLCPP_FIRST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__, "")), \
        RCLCPP_ALL_BUT_FIRST_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__,"")); \
  } while (0)
```

So decoding this, it basically just calls `RCUTILS_LOG_DEBUG_NAMED`, with a little bit of extra overhead to get the name of the logger you are using, which is negligible, and some magic to ensure the first argument is a C string that also should be very cheap, and some static type checks at the beginning that only affect compilation time.

So I'd just continue using the RCLCPP macros if you're working in C++, unless your profiling shows you have a bottleneck here :)

NB the snippet above is from Foxy, but for Dashing [it is not different in a way that affects your question](https://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rclcpp/logging_8hpp.html#a44818c8a1fd292cd0e81759e956765d7).

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kappa95](https://answers.ros.org/users/61250/kappa95/) on 2021-04-22**:
Thank you so much!